# Long running chef-client executions

Tags: automation, chef-infra, chef-recipe, devops

- I'm using a open-source chef server managing about 150 nodes.
- Analytics/Reporting module is not activated in the chef server due to resource constraints.
- "chef-client" is running on all the nodes every 30 minutes

How can I find, how much time each chef-client run is taking to complete?
I'm trying to find the nodes that are slowest in completing their chef-client runs

Comment: https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html#id3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef Server doesn't store this information. You'll need to manage it yourself, possibly using a handler as linked above in the comments. A simple option would be to make a handler which stores the duration of the last run as a node attribute, but the sky is the limit. If you want something to help debug long runs once you find them, check out my poise-profiler cookbook.